# Xamarin plugins conflict. google play services and google maps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin application. I am using the Google Play Services plugin version 117.2.1-preview01. In addition, I want to use google maps in the application, so I added Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 3.3.0.

I am getting the below build error:

```
Version conflict detected for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base. Install/reference 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 117.2.1-preview01 directly to project XamarinApp.Android to 
resolve this issue. XamarinApp.Android -> Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 119.3.1-preview01 -> 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (>= 117.2.1-preview01) XamarinApp.Android -> XamarinApp - 
> Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 3.3.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.1 -> 
amarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (= 60.1142.1).
```

I tried to get the source code and upgrade the version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base used. after that I got an error related to Xamarin.Build.Download v0.10.0:

```
error MSB4064: The "AllowUnsecureUrls" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinDownloadArchives" 
task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
error MSB4063: The "XamarinDownloadArchives" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
```

Can you help please or suggest a work arround other than downgrading Xamarin.Firebase.Auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install the latest prerelease of the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps(v117.0.0-preview03) nuget. No need to edit the source code.